# Cargar la data en un Nested FormArray Dynamic Input en Angular

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, angular7

Necesito el apoyo para poder cargar la informacion que viene de data (informacion persistente del Backend) hacia el input nested dynamic que se encuentra a continuacion:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-385oda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

En el siguiente codigo indico como realice la carga del primer input dinamico, pero no consigo cargar toda la informacion en el html en el momento que deseo realizar la edicion:

```
for (const i in this.resource) {
  const control = this.resourceForm.controls[i];
  if (control != null && i !== 'constructor') {
      const objV = this.resource[i];
      if (Array.isArray(objV)) {
        const formArray = this.resourceForm.controls[i] as FormArray;
        formArray.removeAt(0);
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const key in objV) {
            const element = objV[key];
            // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
            const formArray = this.resourceForm.controls[i] as FormArray;
            formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group(element));
        }
      } else
            this.resourceForm.controls[i].setValue(objV);
  }
}
```

Agradeciendo de antemano todo el apoyo que puedan brindarme, con la solucion seria excelente o con alguna dica para cargar dicha informacion en el html...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, yo conseguí rellenar el formulario con los datos dados.

Introduce este código en el ngOnInit despues de data

```
 const linesFormArray = this.empForm.get("employees") as FormArray;
    data.employees.forEach((a,index) => {


       linesFormArray.push(this.newEmployee());
       console.log(index)

       const skillsArray = linesFormArray.at(index).get('skills') as FormArray;
       a.skills.forEach((skills,i) => {

         skillsArray.push(this.newSkill());
         skillsArray.at(i).setValue(skills)

       })
       linesFormArray.at(index).setValue(a)



    })
```

La información la he cogido de :
https://dev.to/crazedvic/using-patchvalue-on-formarrays-in-angular-7-2c8c y
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: He intentado agregarlo al codigo pero no me funciona, la data viene vacio en BaseResourceForm que donde se carga la infomacion... no he conseguido manera de cargar la informacion aunque la inyecto en el ciclo de vida de angular... Hay forma de mostrarte el codigo ya sea como skype para compartir pantalla???

Comment: que raro, en el link the stackblitz que pasaste a mi me funciona.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-385oda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: En el link funciona pero en el proyecto no, ya que la data viene de un componente que esta en el implements, creo que debo generar esa data en el constructor y lalamrlo despues en el OnInit